# How to make local python script use local package after pushing to pypi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, pypi

After pushing to PyPI and installing your package, python scripts will default to importing from your pip repository which will make developing on your local computer difficult since the script won't run the local package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to have a [virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) set up and that the shebang on the top of your script is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 3.x
```

with the x corresponding to the python version it must be compatible with and what version is in your virtual environment.